# what does the multithreaded connection pool means?

Tags: java, android, performance

Hi can you please enlighten my mind what what does the multithreaded connection pool means? because i heard that httpclient can allow multithreaded connection pool. what does it mean?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, elaborate a little bit more your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection pooling is a concept of maintaining particular no of connection objects in a pool.So that there will be decrease in runtime overhead.Instead of creating objects at runtime
when request comes an connection object is pulled from the pool and used, after completion object will be sent back to pool.

We are not supposed to open or close the connection it will take place automatically which is a  costly operation.

You can refer this link for sample code
http://javaprogramming.language-tutorial.com/2012/09/a-sample-java-code-for-connection.html